# Compare Series and Integer got "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Tags: python

I know got error "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." when compare series and integer but I can't fix this problem.
**cari** function return series, integer or -1,-1. Now, I store the first element cari() to recom on **rimakata** function. If cari return -1,-1 and I have condition recom==-1 there is no problem there. But I got problem when recom is a series and I compare it with -1. I want when I compare series with -1 (integer) is False but I don't get it. Anyone can help me fix my code? Thank you.

[image: Code]

Comment: Instead of returning -1,-1 from cari, return None and then inside rimakata, check if recom is None and handle that -1,-1 case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactor your code to something like this:

```py
def cari(word, kamus):
  # ...
  return None
```

```py
def rimkata(word, kamus):
  recom = cari(word, kamus)
  if recom is None:
    # ...
  else:
    recom = recom[0]
    # ...
```

Also, you have `print` statements after `return`, so they won't work unless you move them up.